# How to read specific folder(which has images) from sdcard and then display as slideshow

Tags: android, image, view, gallery

I want to build an application which will read a specific folder from the `sdcard` and then display images in that folder using `GalleryView`.

Comment: No offense, but your question comes off as if you haven't done any work yet. If you have more specific question about code or errors, you should ask that. Otherwise, read through demos and sample projects until you actually have a more specific problem.

Comment: yes I have done some coding, but i was able to fetch images from sdcard and put it in gridview with scroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi use the code below for getting the images from a specific directory

```
public void walkdir() {

        File dir =new File(getExternalFilesDir(), "urdir");
        String filePattern = ".png";

        File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();

        if (listFile != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                    walkdir(listFile[i]);
                } else {
                    if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(filePattern)){
                       //Do what ever u want
                       //  Log.e("PDF",listFile[i].getName());
                       //here you will get the files
                    }
                }
            }
        }    
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer can you please walk me through your code.

Comment: hi i am trying work with the code here but when i put it in eclipse it is giving me errors.

Comment: it is giving me error on walkdir(listFile[i]);  and if it does store it array how can i display them one by one. you know kind of slide show. taking images from certain folder and displaying them